# Extract each of the multi index of a dataframe in form of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following dataframe which was obtained after filtering my original dataframe, which is multi-indexed. I want to extract multi indices of the rows of the filtered dataframe in the form of list of  tuple, where each tuple represents the multi index of each row.

I tried doing df.index, but it gives me the entire array of the unique values 'id' and 'rollno' index.

I tried doing df[0] , this will give me a multi index of the first row (31,2) in tuple format, but I want to extract the multi index of all the rows in the follwing format:

[(31,2),(31,4), (32,4)...]

df[0:-1] gives me an error.

```
            value          
id rollno                              
31   2        1.100550 
     4        0.936825  
32   4        0.974858  
33   0        1.064065  
     4        0.896980  
34   2        1.005280  
35   1        0.984200
```

Comment: `df.index.values`

Comment: `df.index.values.tolist()` if you want in list instead of array.